# Kivy app crashes on Android when loading a video

Tags: kivy, apk, ffpyplayer

I have created an app that uses a button to open a new screen that plays a video using kivy VideoPlayer. The app works fine on windows but when I run on Android, the app crashes when trying to open the screen where the video will be playing. Below is the logcat output right after the the crash. I could use help interpreting the log to determine what might be causing the crash.

```
01-09 20:38:33.731  1564  1733 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <Extra/Pics and Vids/Videos/db_shoulder_press.mp4>
01-09 20:38:33.788  1248 32081 D SemWifiUsabilityStatsMonitor: onWifiUsabilityStats - seqNum 21663, isSameBssidAndFreq true
01-09 20:38:33.789  1248  2120 D ConnectivityService: notifyType CALLBACK_CAP_CHANGED for [221 WIFI]
01-09 20:38:33.791  1248  2181 I SemWifiLinkQualityMonitor: Link Qos Query: 0.040 ms / 201.599 Mbps (866 / 0.030 / 1.009)
01-09 20:38:33.791  1248  2157 D SemWifiSwitchForIndividualAppsService: stopTCPMonitoring : already stopped
01-09 20:38:33.791  1248  2157 I WifiConnectivityMonitor.NCC: sNetworkCallback(oCC) FULL : 221[ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED&NOT_VCN_MANAGED LinkUpBandwidth>=22390Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=47711Kbps TransportInfo: <SSID: <unknown ssid>, BSSID: 02:00:00:00:00:00, MAC: 02:00:00:00:00:00, IP: /10.0.0.50, Security type: 2, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, Wi-Fi standard: 5, RSSI: -47, Link speed: 866Mbps, Tx Link speed: 866Mbps, Max Supported Tx Link speed: 866Mbps, Rx Link speed: 650Mbps, Max Supported Rx Link speed: 866Mbps, Frequency: 5240MHz, Net ID: -1, Metered hint: false, score: 60, isUsable: true, CarrierMerged: false, SubscriptionId: -1, IsPrimary: 1, Trusted: true, Restricted: false, Ephemeral: false, OEM paid: false, OEM private: false, OSU AP: false, FQDN: <none>, Provider friendly name: <none>, Requesting package name: <none><none>MLO Information: , AP MLD Address: <none>, AP MLO Link Id: <none>, AP MLO Affiliated links: <none>> SignalStrength: -47 AdminUids: [1000] SSID: "The Holy Grail" UnderlyingNetworks: Null]
01-09 20:38:33.791  1248  2157 I WifiConnectivityMonitor.NCC: sNetworkCallback(oCC) (true/false)
01-09 20:38:33.793  1248  2197 I WifiConnectivityMonitor: current mode : 1
01-09 20:38:33.793  1248  2197 D OpenNetworkQos[4.00]: updateBssidNoInternet: mBssidNoInternet = false
01-09 20:38:33.793  1248  2197 D OpenNetworkQos[4.00]: getOpenNetworkQosNoInternetStatus: false
01-09 20:38:33.793  1248  2197 D OpenNetworkQos[4.00]: getOpenNetworkQosScores: 26 26 26
01-09 20:38:33.793  1248  2197 D SettingsProvider: isChangeAllowed() : name = wifi_wcm_qos_sharing_score_summary
01-09 20:38:33.794  5977  6939 I HBD     : g onCapabilitiesChanged network : 221 current network state : wifi
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  2197 I WifiProfileShare: network QoS data was changed (internet), updateQoSData networkType: true, qosData: false
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  3480 V WifiProfileShare.Caster: update wips network, size: 0
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare: nearby scanning settings run
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare: network score provider settings enabled
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  3480 D OpenNetworkQos[4.00]: getOpenNetworkQosScores: 26 26 26
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  3480 D OpenNetworkQos[4.00]: getOpenNetworkQosNoInternetStatus: false
01-09 20:38:33.794  1248  3480 I WifiProfileShare.Caster: current network type: 0, score: [26, 26, 26]
01-09 20:38:33.795  1248  3480 V WifiProfileShare.Cache: update network score bc:5b:d5:fb:f2:74
01-09 20:38:33.795  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare.ScanMatcher: getMcfDataList size:2
01-09 20:38:33.795  1248  3480 I WifiProfileShare.Caster: qos data was updated , before:type:QOS, pBssid:a0:27:c8, qosData:7c after:type:QOS, pBssid:a0:27:c8, qosData:7c
01-09 20:38:33.797  2398  2478 D NetworkController.WifiSignalController: notifyListener: visible=true, connected=true, inetCondition=1, isDefault=true, wifiTestReported=true, receivedInetCondition=-1, hideDuringMobileSwitching=false
01-09 20:38:33.797 26542 26556 I ChimeraSrvcProxy: NullBinder for android.net.action.RECOMMEND_NETWORKS triggering remote TransactionTooLargeException due to Service without Chimera impl
01-09 20:38:33.798 26542 26556 W .gms.persistent: Large reply transaction of 1056768 bytes, interface descriptor , code 1
01-09 20:38:33.799  1248  3480 I [MCFSDK_android_1.2.4010]_4_b: isNetworkEnabled - type : 1 ret : true
01-09 20:38:33.799  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare.McfCast: -ME--- mIsNetworkEnabled :true
01-09 20:38:33.799  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare.McfCast: updateQoSData ignored, same contents
01-09 20:38:33.799  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare.MCF: success update QosData !
01-09 20:38:33.800  2379  3295 I LocationAccessPolicy: checkLocationPermission - callingUid: 10457, callingPid: 4066, resultForFine: DENIED_HARD
01-09 20:38:33.800  1248  3480 I [MCFSDK_android_1.2.4010]_4_b: isNetworkEnabled - type : 1 ret : true
01-09 20:38:33.800  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare.McfCast: -ME--- mIsNetworkEnabled :true
01-09 20:38:33.800  1248  3480 D WifiProfileShare.McfCast: -ME--- updatePasswordDate pwdData size:2
01-09 20:38:33.801  2379  3295 I LocationAccessPolicy: checkLocationPermission - callingUid: 10457, callingPid: 4066, resultForCoarse: DENIED_HARD
01-09 20:38:33.801  2398  2478 D Tile.WifiTile: handleUpdateState isTransient=false transientEnabling =false cb.isTransient=false state.state = 2 mStateBeforeClick.value =false enabled =true
01-09 20:38:33.854  1564  2290 I AAudio  : AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream() called ----------------------------------------
01-09 20:38:33.854  1564  2290 I AudioStreamBuilder: rate   =  48000, channels  = 2, channelMask = 0x80000003, format   = 1, sharing = SH, dir = OUTPUT
01-09 20:38:33.854  1564  2290 I AudioStreamBuilder: device =      0, sessionId = -1, perfMode = 10, callback: OFF with frames = 0
01-09 20:38:33.854  1564  2290 I AudioStreamBuilder: usage  =      0, contentType = 0, inputPreset = 0, allowedCapturePolicy = 0
01-09 20:38:33.854  1564  2290 I AudioStreamBuilder: privacy sensitive = false, opPackageName = (null), attributionTag = (null)
01-09 20:38:33.856  1564  2290 D AudioStreamBuilder: build() MMAP not used because AAUDIO_PERFORMANCE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY not requested.
01-09 20:38:33.856  1564  2290 D ercise.com.yhwh: PlayerBase::PlayerBase()
01-09 20:38:33.856  1564  2290 D AudioStreamTrack: open(), request notificationFrames = 0, frameCount = 0
01-09 20:38:33.856  1105  1786 D AudioFlinger: ro.audio.silent is ignored since no output device is set
01-09 20:38:33.856  1105  1769 D AudioFlinger: ro.audio.silent is ignored since no output device is set
01-09 20:38:33.858  1105  1800 D AudioFlinger: ro.audio.silent is ignored since no output device is set
01-09 20:38:33.858  1105  1788 D AudioFlinger: ro.audio.silent is ignored since no output device is set
01-09 20:38:33.859  1105  1801 D AudioFlinger: ro.audio.silent is ignored since no output device is set
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: getOutputForAttrInt() attributes={ Content type: AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC Usage: AUDIO_USAGE_MEDIA Source: AUDIO_SOURCE_DEFAULT Flags: 0x400 Tags:  } stream=AUDIO_STREAM_MUSIC session 35713 selectedDeviceId 0
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 I APM_AudioPolicyManager: selectOutputFlags: remove ULL flag for dolby
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: getOutputForAttrInt() device {AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER, @:}, sampling rate 48000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x3, flags 0x8 stream AUDIO_STREAM_MUSIC
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: selectOutput new bestOutput 13 criteria 0 100 0 0 0 0 4 2
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: selectOutput new bestOutput 21 criteria 0 100 0 0 0 1 2 0
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: getOutputForAttrInt returns output 21 selectedDeviceId 3
01-09 20:38:33.862  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: getOutputForAttr() returns output 21 requestedPortId 0 selectedDeviceId 3 for port ID 4205
01-09 20:38:33.863  1105  4395 I AudioFlinger: nonSecFlag 0, secFlag 0, outputFlags 8
01-09 20:38:33.863  1105  4395 D AudioFlinger: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 1282 for frameCount 3848
01-09 20:38:33.863  1564  1733 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 1733 (SDLThread), pid 1564 (SDLActivity)
01-09 20:38:33.865  1105  4395 D AF::TrackHandle: OpPlayAudio: track:3434 usage:1 not muted
01-09 20:38:33.866  1105  4395 I AF::Track: setMixerOutConfig expectKey 202
01-09 20:38:33.866  1105  4395 I AF::Track: setMixerOutConfig select, mixer out f 5, s 48000, thread out f 4, s 48000
01-09 20:38:33.877  1564  2290 D AudioTrack: setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000) pid : 1564
01-09 20:38:33.877  1564  2290 D AAudioStream: setState(s#1) from 0 to 2
01-09 20:38:33.879  1564  2290 I AAudio  : AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream() returns 0 = AAUDIO_OK for s#1 ----------------
01-09 20:38:33.879  1564  2290 D AAudio  : AAudioStream_requestStart(s#1) called --------------
01-09 20:38:33.879  1564  2290 D AAudioStream: setState(s#1) from 2 to 3
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 I AF::Track: setMixerOutConfig expectKey 202
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 I AF::Track: setMixerOutConfig select, mixer out f 5, s 48000, thread out f 4, s 48000
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 I AudioPolicyEffectException: MySpaceHandler::checkDetachCondition media 1, ring 0, mp 0
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 I AudioPolicyEffectException: MySpace detach value 1
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: startOutput portId 4205
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: startOutput() output 21, stream 3, session 35713
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: setBeaconMute(1) mBeaconMuteRefCount=26 mBeaconPlayingRefCount=0
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: selectOutputForMusicEffects activeOnly 1 output 21 flags 0x00000008
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 W AudioFlinger: moveEffectChain_l() effect chain for session 0 not on source thread 0xb4000079bd440850
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: selectOutputForMusicEffects selected output 21
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: getNewOutputDevices selected devices {AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER, @:}
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevices device {AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER, @:} delayMs 0
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevices() prevDevice {AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER, @:}
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevices: suppressing checkDeviceMuteStrategies
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevices setting same device {AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_SPEAKER, @:} or null device, force=0, patch handle=4134
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: computeVolume: stream 3, index 7, volume 0.050119, deviceTypes 0x2
01-09 20:38:33.879  1105  4395 V APM_AudioPolicyManager: computeVolume: stream 3, index 8, volume 0.070795, deviceTypes 0x2
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 V sec_audio_hw: sec_dev_set_parameters : l_stream_music_active=true
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 D audio_hw_primary: adev_set_parameters: enter: l_stream_music_active=true
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 D audio_hw_hfp: hfp_set_parameters: enter
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 V audio_hw_sec: sec_set_parameters: enter: l_stream_music_active=true
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 D AudioSAEffectOffload: update offload effect: VM,0,0,0,0,2,0
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 D audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_fm_set_parameters: Enter
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1812 D audio_hw_primary: adev_set_parameters: exit with code(0)
01-09 20:38:33.881   989  1048 I Audio_a2dpsink_hw: adev_set_parameters: kevpairs=[l_stream_music_active=true]
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  4395 I AudioFlinger: updateStageIndex new -2108
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEffectContext: setParam() received parameter EFFECT_PARAM_SEEK
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEffectContext: handleSeek(end crossfading for seeking operation)
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbCrossfadeProcess: setEnabled transitioning from FADE_TO_BYPASS state to FADE_TO_ACTIVE
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEffectContext: transformExternalGain() volume:0xCD494 fVol:0.050119 extVal:-416
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEffectContext: transformExternalGain() volume:0x1000000 fVol:1.000000 extVal:0
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEndpointParamCache: commitChangedParams()
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEndpointParamCache: commit() Applying parameters for device 0x40000000
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbDap2Process: setParam(preg = #1[0])
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbDap2Process: setSystemGain(vol = 0)
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbDap2Process: setParam(svol = #1[-416])
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEndpointParamCache: doCommit() Committed 2 parameters out of 15.
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEndpointParamCache: commit() Overriding parameters for current device 0x00000002
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 D DlbEndpointParamCache: doCommit() Committed 0 parameters out of 56.
01-09 20:38:33.882  1105  1781 I AudioSAEffectSecPlus: command EFFECT_CMD_SET_VOLUME left = 0.050119, right =0.050119
01-09 20:38:33.882  1564  2290 D AAudio  : AAudioStream_requestStart(s#1) returned 0 ---------
01-09 20:38:33.882  1564  2315 D AudioStreamLegacy: onAudioDeviceUpdate(deviceId = 3)
01-09 20:38:33.883  1105  1781 D DlbCrossfadeProcess: process transitioning from FADE_TO_ACTIVE state to DAP_ACTIVE
01-09 20:38:33.883  1105  1781 I SoundAlive_Interface a64: [ 2 ][ 48000 ]FlushBuffers()
01-09 20:38:33.883   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xea58c970)usecase(0: deep-buffer-playback) devices(0x2) is_haptic_usecase(0)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: select_devices for use case (deep-buffer-playback)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 I sm8250_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 24, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 0 device (speaker)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 I sm8250_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg: new_snd_devices[0] is 2
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 I sm8250_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 24, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 0 device (speaker)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: updated afe: bitwidth 24, samplerate 48000 channels 2,backend_idx 0 usecase = 0 device (speaker)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: playback on codec device not supporting native playback set default Sample Rate(48k)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 I sm8250_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: Codec selected backend: 0 updated bit width: 24 and sample rate: 48000
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: force routing 1
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 E sm8250_platform: platform_check_backends_match: Invalid snd_device =
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: (81) check_usecases curr device: speaker, usecase device: backends match 0
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: check_usecases num.of Usecases to switch 0
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 V audio_hw_sec: sec_dsm_spkr_prot_control_tx_topology() enable:1, dsm_is_enabled:0
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = vi-feedback
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(299: vi-feedback)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_get_island_cfg_on_device:island cfg status on snd_device = (vi-feedback 0)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 I soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x12b of type 1 for Event 1, with Raise=0
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_route: Apply path: vi-feedback
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: uc_info->id 79 of type 1 for Event 3, with Raise=0
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg: usecase->in_snd_device vi-feedback
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 E voice   : voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(299) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 E voice   : voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
01-09 20:38:33.884   989 28053 I audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device default app_type 69938, acdb_dev_id 102, sample_rate 48000, snd_device_be_idx 56
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(299) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 102, path = 1, app id = 0x11132, sample rate = 48000, afe_sample_rate = 48000
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL cal_type[11] acdb_id[102] app_type[69938]
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_PERSISTENT_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D android.hardware.audio.service: [Data Manager]-> No data found
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_PERSISTENT_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE returned -18
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audproc_persist_table -18
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: Invalid Audproc persist size = -18
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_STREAM_TABLE_SIZE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audstrmtable
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_STREAM_TABLE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> audstrm_cal->cal_type.cal_data.cal_size = 20
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_topology
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID for adcd_id 102, Topology Id 112fb
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 00000066
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D android.hardware.audio.service: Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 00000066
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL cal_type[17] acdb_id[102]
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_hw_delay : acdb_id = 102 path = 1
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply mixer and update path: spkr-vi-feedback
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D audio_route: Apply path: spkr-vi-feedback
01-09 20:38:33.885   989 28053 D AudioSAEffectOffload: update offload effect: VM,0,0,0,0,2,0
01-09 20:38:33.886  1248  2143 D AS.SoundAliveHelper: notify dvfs state : 2, screen : true
01-09 20:38:33.886  1248  1248 D AudioPlayerStateMonitor: Found a new active media playback. AudioPlaybackConfiguration piid:28015 deviceId:3 type:AAudio u/pid:10266/1564 state:started attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_MEDIA content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null sessionId:-1
01-09 20:38:33.890 31579 31622 I SAContentProvider:  getType() : screen on is true
01-09 20:38:33.895  5977  5977 I HBD     : g onCapabilityChanged  setNetworkState currentNetworkState : wifi
01-09 20:38:33.896  1248  1248 I GestureDetector: handleMessage TAP
01-09 20:38:33.896  1248  1546 I GestureDetector: handleMessage TAP
01-09 20:38:33.905   989 28053 V audio_hw_sec: sec_dsm_spkr_prot_control_tx_topology() dsm enabled (c:0 d:1 m:0)
01-09 20:38:33.905   989 28053 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: dual-speaker)
01-09 20:38:33.905   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_get_island_cfg_on_device:island cfg status on snd_device = (speaker 0)
01-09 20:38:33.905   989 28053 I soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 1, with Raise=0
01-09 20:38:33.905   989 28053 D audio_route: Apply path: dual-speaker
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 I audio_hw_utils: set_app_type_cfg app_type_cfg->app_type 69940 -> 69941 sample_rate 48000, bit_width 24
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 I audio_hw_utils: set_app_type_cfg app_type_cfg->app_type 69941, app_type_cfg->sample_rate 48000, app_type_cfg->bit_width 24
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 E soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: invalid input device 0x0, for event 3
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: uc_info->id 0 of type 0 for Event 3, with Raise=0
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg: usecase->out_snd_device speaker
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 I audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device PLAYBACK app_type 69941, acdb_dev_id 13, sample_rate 48000, snd_device_be_idx 55
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D sm8250_platform: platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 13, path = 0, app id = 0x11135, sample rate = 48000, afe_sample_rate = 48000
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_INSTANCE_COMMON_TABLE
01-09 20:38:33.910   989 28053 D ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL cal_type[11] acdb_id[13]
```

I have tried clearing the app cache on android which seemed to work at first but has since stopped preventing the crash.

Comment: Make sure the media file path is consistent with Android file path. Most often the problem occurs due to the wrong file path.

Comment: `Extra/Pics and Vids/Videos/db_shoulder_press.mp4` does not look like a valid path on Android. Do use the path shown via MTP in Windows/Linux/MacOS because MTP path is virtual and does not exist on device with that name.

Comment: Does that require naming my folder something specific on Windows or is that a setting I need to adjust in the buildozer.spec file?